# Twig `constant()` as array key

Tags: php, symfony, twig

How can I use a class constant as key in a Twig array/object/hashmap? When I try this

```
{ constant('App\\Entity\\User::FOO'): 'bar' }
```

... I'm getting this error:

> A hash key must be followed by a colon (:). Unexpected token "punctuation" of value "(" ("punctuation" expected with value ":").

However, it does work the other way aroung (i.e. using the constant as value):

```
{ 'bar': constant('App\\Entity\\User::FOO') }
```

Answer (score 5):

Just enclose the `constant()` in parentheses, like this:

```
{ (constant('App\\Entity\\User::FOO')): 'bar' }
```